# Loops reduction for simple restaurant menu function

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm working on a script to list the restaurant's menu for the week. I need to list 4 types of dishes for a specific day with a header of the name of the day and date.

```
Monday 2020-12-07
- menu 1
- menu 2
- menu 3
- menu 4

Tuesday 2020-12-08
- menu 1
- menu 2
- menu 3
- menu 4
...
```

Array from database

```
$menu = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2020-12-07
            [meal] => Vývar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2020-12-07
            [meal] => šošovicová
        )
...
```

I code something like this, but I don't like it.

```
 
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($menu); $i++) {

   $date = $menu[$i]['day'];
   $compare_date;

   if ($date != $compare_date) {

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . date('l', strtotime($date)) . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";

      $compare_date = $date;

      foreach($menu as $id) {

         if ($id['day'] === $compare_date) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $id['meal'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>"; 

         }
      }
   }
}
```

I need help with refactoring. I think such a simple menu listing could be done with fewer lines of code, but I don't know how to do it. I've been sitting there for a few hours and I really can't think of anything. Please guide me to the correct way.

Comment: This is a pretty clean solution already, considering the array is structured awkwardly and you have to echo out HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that. Array is unfortunately the result of the PDO fetchAll function. However, thanks to @Taavi, I changed the code a bit and saved one condition and the foreach loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Add order by day clause to your SQL query, if its not there already.
Then You can do it with one loop.

Something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($menu); $i++) {
  $date = $menu[$i]['day'];
  $compare_date;
  echo "<tr><td>". ($date != $compare_date ? date('l Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) : ' - ') ."</td><td>" . $menu[$i]['meal'] . "</td></tr>";
  $compare_date = $date;
}
```